# Python: Item exists in dictionary inside list

Tags: python, list

```
b = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]
```

How can I determine if b has an entry `'a'=5`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `any()` with a generator expression:

```
if any(x["a"] == 5 for x in b):
    # whatever
```

This will stop iterating `b` as soon as the first match is found.

If you like functional programming, you can also do

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import imap
if 5 in imap(itemgetter("a"), b):
    # whatever
```

I'm pretty sure though most people, me included, would prefer the first variant.